# SQL, small program to run a query based on the input the user provides

Tags: sql, windows

I'm looking into creating a small SQL based program that will run a single query based on an input from a user, but to be honest I know SQL but have no idea on any other Programming language.
Does anyone know if someone has developed something like this, and if so a link to where to find it?

to give an idea, 
A windows box pops up with an entry field, that entry field is using the "set @Query" Declarable variable, it then runs a pre-existing SQL Query on that variable and prints to the user the result.

If anything is unclear please let me know
Your humble newbie.

Denslat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sqlcmd utility, it's a part of SQL Server. For more info, see [this link.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You don't have to learn new language, you just need to know how to get an user input and call query.

For mode advance situations, you can even couple sqlcmd with PowerShell. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx).

Comment: Not quite what I was expecting, but useful none the less.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Oracle Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) in your system. It has an **interactive** and **batch** query tool namely **SQL*Plus** which has its own command line interface,GUI and web based interface. You can run your own interactive *SQL* script in its Command Line Interface very easily. In future, for more advanced development, you can use Oracle [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

And you need not know any other programming language. Just learn how to get input from user in SQL. Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: The company I work for, won't install oracle, as it is too expensive.